# Customer Churn Calculation

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery, business-intelligence, churn

I am currently working on query in which I want to calculate how many customers placed an order with us historically but not in the current month

The final output should look like this

| Month | Churned_Customers |
| --- | --- |
| January | 23 |
| Feburary | 32 |

By number 23 in the first row I mean all those customers which placed atleast one order till december but not in the month of january and by 32 I mean how many customers placed atleast 1 order till january but no in feburary

Currently the data I have is
customer_id, delivery_date (datetimestamp_format),order_id
I am using Google Bigqeury platform.

Till now I just came up with this

`DATE_TRUNC((delivery_date),MONTH) AS Month, customer_id, COUNT(DISTINCT order_id) AS orders  FROM orders WHERE LOWER(order_status) = 'delivered' GROUP BY 1,2 )`

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055). Also, you'll find your experiences at SO will be much better if you take the time to go through the [tour] and read the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.